# Change Font in Grid Header

Tags: grid-layouts, style

How can I style headers in a grid to be in Arial, 20pt?

```
g = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}];
headers={"A", "B", "C"};
Grid[Prepend[{{g, g, g}}, headers]]
```

[image: Grid of plots with unformatted headers]

(I decided to post this question/answer because I keep stumbling onto this. I know the answer is somewhere in some question but always have a hard time finding the related question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ItemStyle` option of `Grid`.

```
Grid[Prepend[{{g, g, g}}, headers],
 ItemStyle -> {Automatic, {1 -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 20}}}]
```

[image]

This `ItemStyle` specification says use `Automatic` styling for the columns. Use *Arial 20pt* for row `1`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

Using the `Style` function with `Slot` (`#`), `Function` (`&`) and `Map` (`/@`)

```
headers = Style[#, {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 20}] & /@ {"A", "B", "C"}
Grid[Prepend[{{g, g, g}}, headers]]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with the special characters in Mathematica. I just discovered the Slot, could someone point me to the names of the other two?

Comment: `/@` is simply `Map`. You can usually figure them out by entering `? /@` or something like `FullForm[f /@ g]`.

Comment: Thank you! Edited to add that info.

Comment: @MartinBüttner - but the one that drove me up a wall was that you can't use the question mark on any of these:  `{@, @@, @@@}`.  @Delphine - see this post:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616

Comment: @JasonB Oh, that's true. It seems that the only thing that still works on those is F1.